# Can't Start Apache After Manual Installation on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, apache2

My vm is within a closed network so I cannot use `apt install apache2`. Instead, I installed manually by the following steps:

1. `tar -xzvf httpd-2.4.51.tar.gz` in `/home/my_username` directory, obtaining `httpd-2.4.51` directory
2. Placed `apr-1.7.0.tar.gz`, `apr-iconv-1.2.2.tar.gz` and `apr-util-1.6.1.tar.gz` under`httpd-2.4.51/srclib/` and `tar -xzvf` all of them
3. Renamed these unpacked APR directories by omitting their versions, e.g. `apr-util-1.6.1` to `apr-util` with `mv apr-util-1.6.1 apr-util`
4. `tar -xzvf pcre-8.45.tar.gz` in `/home/my_username` directory, obtaining `pcre-8.45` directory
5. `cd pcre-8.45` and `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/pcre; make; make install`
6. Finally installed Apache by `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 --with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre; make; make install`

I checked the `/usr/local/apache2` folder, everything seemed fine. But when I tried to start Apache with `systemctl start apache2`, cmd said `Failed to start apache2.service: Unit apache2.service not found.`. Is it possible that the device cannot recognize Apache even after installation, or should I register Apache as Linux service something? Most solutions on the net assume using the `apt install apache2` approach and the system will handle all the required stuff at the back. For my case, I believe I have missed some configuration settings so I've been stuck here. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Do you have a `/var/log/apache` directory? If so, the error log should have a detailed description for why it can’t start. Alternatively, `/var/log/syslog` may have some details. If AppArmor is running on the VM, you’ll want to ensure the Apache directories you’re using are available to the service.

Comment: are you using sudo at the beginning of each command? in other words, are the commands running as super user? ex: sudo systemctl start apache2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the `.deb` package for your distro and installing it `dpkg`. (e.g. `dpkg -i package.deb`)

source: https://pkgs.org/download/apache2

Answer (score 0):

Without internet access, it is very difficult to build apache2 with all the dependencies.
Alternative option: Install Ubuntu 20.04 with internet access(you can use Ubuntu 20.04 live iso running from usb).

```
Run in the terminal mkdir ${HOME}/apache2 && cd apache2
```

Reading the answers https://askubuntu.com/search?q=recursively+list+dependencies

```
Download the packages to the apache2 folder
apt-get download $(apt-cache depends --recurse --no-recommends --no-suggests --no-conflicts --no-breaks --no-replaces --no-enhances apache2 | grep "^\w" |grep -v "i386" | sort -u)
grep -v "i386" (To ignore the i386 ones)
```

Copy the apache2 folder to a vm without the Internet.

```
In the apache2 folder, run sudo dpkg -i *.deb in the terminal
```